# Getting argument passed into ArgumentCaptor of functional interface

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have an interface

```
MyFunctionalInterface<T> {
   T execute(SomeClass var)
}
```

I also have an object I am mocking that calls a method

```
myObject.myMethod(var -> someOtherMethod(var, arg))
```

I am mocking this object by stating

```
ArgumentCaptor<MyFunctionalInterface> functionalInterfaceCaptor;
...
when(myMockObject.myMethod(functionalInterfaceCaptor.capture())).then(doSomething)
```

I'd like to get the value of `arg` from my `functionalInterfaceCaptor`. I know that it is storing this value because when I go into the Intellij debugger and click on `functionalInterfaceCaptor` I can look at the private field `capturingMatcher` and then the field `arguments` of that, which is a linked list containing the value of `var` and the value of `arg`. However, I can't figure out what methods I need to call on `functionalInterfaceCaptor` to see these in my tests (`ArgumentCaptor` does not expose any). How do I get the value of `arg`?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `myObject.myMethod(var -> someOtherMethod(var, arg))` then the method's parameter is the lambda `var -> someOtherMethod(var, arg)`. Therefore your `functionalInterfaceCaptor` captures the lambda itself, not the parameters it is called with.

If you want to capture `arg` then you have to mock the object `someOtherMethod` is defined on and setup an `ArgumentCaptor` for this method.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use [ArgumentMatcher](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)?

when(myMockObject.myMethod(new ArgumentMatcher (functionalInterfaceCaptor)).then(doSomething)